# Contenteditable issue when div out of focus and text added to ngmodel

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, contenteditable

So I'm having an issue with using a contenteditable div in my angularjs application.

Let's say i have an tag like

```
<div contenteditable = true ng-model = something></div>
```

so When I add text to the ngmodel model value like `$scope.something = $scope.something+ 'text';` the text is being added to the next line in my div.  Also the text is only being added by some modal after the user clicks confirm.

How can I add text to `contenteditable` and have it be on the same line as the text that already exists/ is present?

Comment: div tag got deleted but it looks like, div contenteditable= true ng-model=something

Comment: Please show us the code for the contenteditable directive.

Answer (score 0):

contenteditable tag will not work with ng-model, you need to create a custom directive to achive this.